# Altering external data like a python list

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a problem that seems like it should be simple in my head but i'm struggling to figure out the simplest way of executing it.

Basically, I have 2 lists of names:

```
list1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
list2 = ['name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10']
```

My ultimate goal is, when the python script is run, i will return 1 random name from each list but ideally the script would not return the same name from either list for the next 4 times it was run. Essentially, i want each run's pair/choice to be random but i want it to restart the rotation every 5 times the script is run.

I think I'll need to store the data externally. Conceptually, i think i need the script to move a name from one list to another list every time it's run and when the first list is empty, it reverses and moves the names the other way and so on.

Should i use the `csv.DictReader` to move names between two CSV? or store them in a JSON?

Forgive me if this doesn't make sense. I'm struggling to put my problem into words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just store it in a text file?

```
import random

list1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
list2 = ['name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10']

used = open("old.txt").readlines()

l1_copy = list1[:]
l2_copy = list2[:]
for line in used:
    if line := line.strip():
        a, b = line.split(",")
        l1_copy.remove(a)
        l2_copy.remove(b)

if not l1_copy or not l2_copy:
    # clear file
    with open("old.txt", "w"): pass
else:
    list1 = l1_copy
    list2 = l2_copy

choice1, choice2 = random.choice(list1), random.choice(list2)

print("Choice 1:", choice1)
print("Choice 2:", choice2)

with open("old.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(choice1 + "," + choice2 + "\n")
```

Make a file named `old.txt` in your current directory. It will store the previous runs, comma-separated.

Example run:

```
$ python3.8 choose_from_list.py 
Choice 1: name2
Choice 2: name9
$ python3.8 choose_from_list.py 
Choice 1: name5
Choice 2: name10
$ python3.8 choose_from_list.py 
Choice 1: name4
Choice 2: name6
$ python3.8 choose_from_list.py 
Choice 1: name1
Choice 2: name7
$ python3.8 choose_from_list.py 
Choice 1: name3
Choice 2: name8
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! You helped me realise that i didn't need to externally store both lists and mutate both of them.

I ended up using your idea of storing the old (used) names in a txt file. I then converted that and my original list to an array and used numpy's setdiff1d method to return unique values between them.

Thanks again for your help!